# How to set background color in vaadin grid header cells

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

How can I set the background color of the header of a grid(table) in Vaadin.
I tried to use:

```
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(cellRef -> (REFERENCES_INCLUDED_COLUMN + levelList.get(0).getName()).equals(cellRef.getProperty()) ? "rightalign" : null);
```

where the REFERENCES_INCLUDED_COLUMN has the header information and right align is the CSS styling. But I didn't work.

IS there any css styling which I can do?

Comment: How is `rightalign` defined in your theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer some where on Vaadin forum. Instead of using

```
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(cellRef -> (REFERENCES_INCLUDED_COLUMN + levelList.get(0).getName()).equals(cellRef.getProperty()) ? "rightalign" : null);
```

which I feel can be useful if we want to do styling for specific cells, I ended up using proper CSS styling

```
.v-grid .v-grid-header th.v-grid-cell {
    background:#5A9CC5;
    color: white;
}
```